# DAX help: % monthly share of another table

Tags: pivot, dax, powerpivot

I have a DAX formula for my Powerpivot I cannot get to solve and was hoping for help.

I have two pivot tables connected already

1. Showing a cohort of actions taken within Month 1,….X on the sign up month
2. Total Sign Ups on monthly basis

I have tried to attached the sheet here but somehow I cant so I have add a screenshot of the sheet.[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EtOhW.png)

What I have so far is: 
`=DIVIDE(
SUM(Range[conversion to KYC completed]),
SUM('Range 1'[Sum of signups]))`

But this does not give me what I want as I think I’m missing the monthly grouping somehow.

Question 1: 
What I want is to get the share of actions completed within 1,...,X months out of the total sign up that given month (e.g. Jan) (so the data from Table 2)

Question 2: 
In best case I would also like to show total sign ups in the beginning of the cohort to make the cohort easier to understand, so having the monthly total sign up (which the cohort is calculated based on). But now I cannot get just the totals month by month. Is there anyways just to add in a monthly total column in the pivot without applying these number as a value across all columns?

Something like this is the ultimate outcome for me [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1erMT.png)

UPDATED WITH SAMPLE DATA

`Signup month,  KYC completed month,    Age by month,   signups,    conversion to KYC completed
Jan-17  Jul-18  18  97  75
Jan-17  Jul-18  18  99  79
Jan-17  Dec-18  23  95  80
Feb-17  May-18  15  99  74
Feb-17  Jul-18  17  90  75
Feb-17  Jul-18  17  95  76
Feb-17  Aug-18  18  92  71
Mar-17  May-18  14  94  73
Apr-17  Jul-18  15  93  75
May-17  Sep-18  16  94  70
May-17  Oct-18  17  98  72
Jun-17  May-18  11  95  79
Jul-17  Oct-18  15  97  74
Jul-17  Jul-18  12  94  78
Aug-17  Sep-18  13  96  74
Sep-17  Nov-18  14  95  80
Sep-17  Oct-18  13  94  79`

DESIRED OUTCOME
The % for Month 1....X is calculated KYC Completed / Monthly Sign up

[image]

OUTPUT WITH THIS CODE
`=VAR SignUpMonth = IF(HASONEVALUE('Range 1'[Row Labels]), BLANK())
RETURN 
    DIVIDE(CALCULATE(SUM([conversion to KYC completed])),
           CALCULATE(SUM('Range 1'[Sum of signups]),
               FILTER(ALL(Range), Range[Signup month (Month Index)] = SignUpMonth)))`

[[image]

Comment: can you post some sample data and maybe a shot o your desired results?

Comment: I have updated the post with sample data and outcome :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the sample data Franzi. Still not too clear what you're asking for, but perhaps this will help a little.

```
Signed Up to Signed In Ratio = 
VAR SignUpMonth = SELECTEDVALUE(Table1[Signup month], BLANK())
RETURN 
    DIVIDE(CALCULATE(SUM([conversion to KYC completed])),
           CALCULATE(SUM(Table1[ signups]),
               FILTER(ALL(Table1), Table1[Signup month] = SignUpMonth)))
```

So. Let's break it down.

If I understand correct, you want to see the cross section of number of signins for a given month ( x axis ) signup combo ( y axis ) and divide that number by the *total* signups ( y axis ) per signup month.

`number of signins for a given month ( x axis ) signup combo ( y axis ):`

```
CALCULATE(SUM([conversion to KYC completed]))
```

`TOTAL signups ( y axis ) per signup month`

```
CALCULATE(SUM(Table1[ signups]),
    FILTER(ALL(Table1), Table1[Signup month] = SignUpMonth))
```

[image]

Comment: This is much appropriated!
I'm playing around wiith it as I get some errors but I definitely think this is the right direction. I will see if I can solve it myself with what you have provided, if not I will get back here :) 
I have also added the desired outcome again - with a exact picture of what i'm looking for. I just calculated in manually in excel.

Comment: I have just been working on it for some hours and I can get the metrics created - the Signup to Sign in ratio is the one I'm looking for. However, when i try to use it in the pivot i get nothing. This is the code i use (had to change Selectedvalue due to Microsoft version)

=VAR SignUpMonth = IF(HASONEVALUE('Range 1'[Row Labels]), BLANK())
RETURN 
    DIVIDE(CALCULATE(SUM([conversion to KYC completed])),
           CALCULATE(SUM('Range 1'[Sum of signups]),
               FILTER(ALL(Range), Range[Signup month (Month Index)] = SignUpMonth)))

See a photo of my pivot returned below

Comment: Photo in the post - I couldnt post photo in comment :)

Comment: Add  a table like so:

Comment: 1 through 24 = GENERATESERIES(1,24,1)

Comment: Add a measure like so:

Comment: Signed Up to Signed In Ratio = VAR SignUpMonth = SELECTEDVALUE(Table1[Signup month]) VAR MonthDiff = SELECTEDVALUE('1 through 24'[Value]) RETURN DIVIDE(CALCULATE(SUM([conversion to KYC completed]), FILTER(Table1, Table1[Month Diff] = MonthDiff)), CALCULATE(SUM(Table1[ signups]), FILTER(ALL(Table1), Table1[Signup month] = SignUpMonth)), BLANK())

Comment: It's still impossible for me to tell if it is right because I don't have all the source data, but this attempts to divide the sum of KYC complete that are x months away from the signup month via KYC date by the number of TOTAL signups for that signup month.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your effort!! I will spend some hours on it again and hopefully get it to work. Again, thanks!